# MVC ADO.net Repostiory without Model is possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to create a generic repository without model implementation.
Is it possible?

```
public interface IRepo
{
   //Return string because jqgrid need json and if i don't need json   
   //I  would process it
   string GetAll(params object[] parameters);
}

public class UserRepository : IRepo       
    {
        public string GetAll(params object[] parameters)
        {
            try
            {
                //In the dataset there is multiple result set 
                //ErrorCode, Userinfo (Username,AccessCode, UserID), 
                //and multiple Organization 
                DataSet ds;
                DALUser DALOsztaly = new DALUser();
                ds = DALOsztaly.LoginDs();
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds.Tables[0]);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
...
}
```

In the controller I would like to get data from dataset/jsonresult.
I tried many suggestion, but no one worked. 
It's because I don't use model?

```
JsonResult j = Json(userrepo.GetAll())
var someObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(loginrepo.GetAll())
```

Comment: Pretty weird to return JSON from your repository. Deciding the format is not a responsibility of the data layer, but of the presentation layer. You should look into generics.

Comment: It looks like your repository works fine.  It's the part where you try to deserialize the JSON into a `var` without specifying a type where things are breaking down.

Comment: In your case you should read more about jqgrid, it allows to change default way how you load data. And you can return class from your repo that will be serialize right way to your jqgrid

Comment: Why not just return the table and then you can construct anonymous types from it in your controller. If you don't want to be tied to the Table then create your own result abstraction from the table that would allow consumers to easily inspect the data. Ive done something similar to this by using `DynamicObject` but that might be more work than you may be willing to embark on.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to reach data like this:
JObject o = JObject.Parse(userrepo.GetAll());
o.SelectToken("Table[0].ErrorCode").ToString()
o.SelectToken("Table1[0].UserName").ToString()

I think it's generics. I don't need create model. I can use my repo interface for CRUD operation. What is your suggestion Leon?
GetAll method can use for jqgrid JSON datasource, and for login too.